# Dictionary with multiple key values to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Dictionary looks like:

```
{'iphone': [12, 21666], 'a1': [6, 5859], 'J5': [15, 13862]}
```

Using this dictionary i want to create dataframe that looks like this:

```
    name   n1   n2
0  iphone  12   21666
1  a1       6   5859
2  J5      15   13862
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use list comprehension with `DataFrame` constructor:

```
d = {'iphone': [12, 21666], 'a1': [6, 5859], 'J5': [15, 13862]}

df = pd.DataFrame([([k] + v) for k, v in d.items()], columns=['name','n1','n2'])
#alternative
#df = pd.DataFrame([(k, *v) for k, v in d.items()], columns=['name','n1','n2'])
print (df)
     name  n1     n2
0  iphone  12  21666
1      a1   6   5859
2      J5  15  13862
```

General solution for list with all lenghts, not only `2`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(k, *v) for k, v in d.items()])
#python 3.6+ with f-strings
df.columns = ['name'] + [f'n{x}' for x in df.columns[1:]]
#python bellow
#df.columns = ['name'] + ['n{}'.format(x) for x in df.columns[1:]]
print (df)
     name  n1     n2
0  iphone  12  21666
1      a1   6   5859
2      J5  15  13862
```

Or:

```
df = (pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
                  .rename(columns=lambda x: x+1)
                  .add_prefix('n')
                  .rename_axis('name')
                  .reset_index())
print (df)
     name  n1     n2
0  iphone  12  21666
1      a1   6   5859
2      J5  15  13862
```

Comment: General solution using dictionary comprehension worked out great, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can just do this, if your dictionary name is `d`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d).T.reset_index()
df.columns = ['name','n1','n2']
```

Comment: The solution gave me an error:
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 2 elements, new values have 3 elements

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try like this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'iphone': [12, 21666], 'a1': [6, 5859], 'J5': [15, 13862]})
df.columns = ["name", "n1", "n2"]
print(df)
```

Comment: No, solution is wrong, check `print(df)` and compare with expected output.

Answer (score 0):

```
a={'iphone': [12, 21666], 'a1': [6, 5859], 'J5': [15, 13862]}
df = pd.DataFrame(a).T
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.columns = ['name','n1','n2']
print(df)
```

output:

```
     name  n1     n2
0  iphone  12  21666
1      a1   6   5859
2      J5  15  13862
```

reset index is require step without it, it will take ['iphone','a1','J5'] as a index